# Is there a way that I can run a ASP.NET MVC Project on godaddy.com shared web hosting?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there a way that I can run a ASP.NET MVC Project on godaddy.com shared web hosting?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about using a third party service.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

As a developer who has deployed an MVC project on GoDaddy's ASP.NET shared hosting, I can tell you with certainty that you can do this, and it's quite easy.

1. First, make sure that you've gotten
   a GoDaddy windows hosting plan (they
   sell both Linux and Windows plans).
2. Next, make sure that you've [set the hosting account to use ASP 2.0/3.0/3.5](http://help.godaddy.com/article/687) (this is enabled by default AFAIK -- but you need to make sure it's set to this if you've changed it in the past).  You set this by clicking 'Manage Account' / Content / IIS Settings.
3. Next, make sure your MVC project is
   set to copy the MVC .dll's to your
   bin directory.  [ASP.NET MVC (as of
   the beta) now puts these assemblies
   in the GAC by default](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/10/16/asp-net-mvc-beta-released.aspx#eleven).  You'll
   need to change this for your
   project.  [Information on how to do
   this is on Phil Haack's website,
   here](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx).
4. Last, just publish your site and
   upload.

It really should be that easy.  Please leave a comment if you have any issues.

Comment: I had to also upgrade to IIS 7 and turn on integrated pipeline (as opposed to classic) found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/705229/diagnosing-404-errors-on-iis-7-and-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Does this apply equally to ASP.NET MVC version 2?

Comment: I found this support article that may be useful, how to change the pipeline mode in Godaddy's control panel: http://help.godaddy.com/article/4179

Comment: @Drew - Yes, although I'm not sure you need to do a bin deploy (step 3) -- you might be able to get away with checking your hosting settings and publishing, I haven't checked.

Comment: @Drew - If you're going to bin deploy MVC3, you do need to deploy different assemblies now.  Hanselman has a great article on this here: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BINDeployingASPNETMVC3WithRazorToAWindowsServerWithoutMVCInstalled.aspx

Comment: @DanEsparza  hii. My godaddy account has server operating system as Linux. Can i deploy Asp.net mvc website into that account? or it works only for windows operating system ??

Comment: It's just Windows that supports ASP.NET MVC.  This help article elaborates: http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/2520/should-i-choose-a-windows-or-linux-hosting-account