# Diagnosing 404 errors on IIS 7 and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7, httphandler

I have an mvc app developed and tested with Cassini. Deployed to my site on GoDaddy, and the default page comes up fine. Click to log in, and I get a 404.

I'm running under IIS 7 there, so this is unexpected. My routes are pretty plain:

```
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           
            new { controller = "Public", action = "Index", id = "" } 
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Report1",
            "Report/{action}/{start}/{end}",
            new { controller = "Report", action = "Index" }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Report2",
            "Report/{action}/{start}/{end}/{idList}",
            new { controller = "Report", action = "Index" }
        );
```

Any idea what might be going on or how I can troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Are you running in IIS7 **integrated mode**?

Classic mode of IIS7 does **not** automatically map extensionless URLs to ASP.NET (much like IIS6).

Also make sure your `Web.config` `<system.webServer>` tag is configured correctly.

Comment: Thanks, Mehrdad. Turns out that GoDaddy defaults IIS 7 to classic mode.

Comment: <system.webServer>
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    </system.webServer>

Answer (score 24):

[Don't use runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests](http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2010/06/dont-use-modules-runallmanagedmodulesfo.html). You want to let IIS handle resources such as images.

```
<system.webServer> <!-- Rather do NOT use this -->
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

Instead add the MVC routing module

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
    <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: This answer also worked and does appear to have a more efficient (and elegant) approach.

Comment: This method worked well for me in an ASP.NET Web API application. The app worked fined locally, but when deployed to any other environment, I just received a 404 for any Web API request. Added the routing module bits noted above and everything is fine. Similar issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15389855/asp-net-web-api-application-gives-404-when-deployed-at-iis-7. Thanks!

Comment: I was pulling my hair out trying to get an MVC app to accept HTTP DELETE requests. This took care of it for me. Thanks!

Comment: same problem, the method delete request  don't work if i deploy to other environment: iis 8 ok but in other environment (iis 7) i get 404

Answer (score 14):

Tried everything, I had to set my web config like this, to make it work.

```
 <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Wow this actually worked! But why do I have the feeling it will come back to haunt me?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I uploaded the controller, web.config and other classes but I forgot to upload the bin folder.

After I uploaded the bin folder, it worked!