# Downloading a file from MongoDB to local filesystem

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have asked various questions and got only limited answers and it has gotten me this far:
Mongoose code :

```
app.get('/Download/:file(*)', function (req, res) {
    grid.mongo = mongoose.mongo;
    var gfs = grid(conn.db);
    var file = req.params.file
    var fs_write_stream = fs.createWriteStream('Program.cs');
    
    var readstream = gfs.createReadStream({ filename: file });
    
    readstream.pipe(fs_write_stream);

    res.download(__dirname+'/Program.cs', 'Solution.cs', function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        else console.log("check console");
    });
})
```

Angular code:

```
$scope.Download = function () {
        $http.get(url + "/Download/"+"Program.cs")
        .success(function (res) {
            console.log(res);
        })}
```

When I open my console angular just returns a blank line, when i look into the network aspect the header sais this:

---

[image: Response Header]

I want to be able to store this file to my local file system to a path that I want to be able to choose myself. PLEASE help me out, I'm desperate, I have looked EVERYwhere for a solution, thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Are you talking about the local filesystem on the *server* or on the *client*? (the latter should be impossible because a website can not tell the web browser where to save a file)

Comment: I just want the client to be able to download a file that is stored in my mongodb, like any other site that allows you to download a file like a .pdf or .txt

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of your client side download attempt:

```html
<a class="btn" href="/Download/Program.cs" download>
```

Comment: gave this error for me: "HTTP Error 404.7 - Not Found
The request filtering module is configured to deny the file extension." this probably because it's a '.cs' file .. but that's how I want to download it. this because it's the point of my website. the teachers are supposed to download these '.cs' files so they can run the code and correct where nessecary

Comment: you need to configure your serving server. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13455939/http-error-404-7-not-found-the-request-filtering-module-is-configured-to-deny

Comment: I got that working, I think.. now it's just telling me "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable." don't know what he's talking about

Comment: Also it shows : "Physical Path
   "path to application file"\Download\Program.cs " but this "\Download" file doesn't exist so ofcourse it's not going to find anything there. what's going on ?

Comment: I just created this filepath myself to see what outcome it would give me, and it gave this "The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map." how do I solve this ? and also, I do I change the directory where it reads from ?

Comment: your nodejs is running behind IIS?

Comment: I truly have no idea how to check that.