# HTTP Error 404.7 - Is there any other option to solve it?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis

I've started learning web services with ASP.NET. When doing a quick search on how to build and use a simple web service, [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/webservices/web_services_examples.htm) page seemed nice and simple.

I followed the instruction "copy FirstService.asmx in the IIS virtual directory...[and] open the web service" (actually, it is displayed as FirstService.asmx.cs), but from there on problems started. I got several HTTP Error (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232922/asp-pages-in-iis-using-localhost-401-3-error-do-not-have-permission#comment58979387_8234073), I gave permissions to both IUSR and IIS_USRS, though the latter is probably irrelevant) and I'm now stuck with Error 404.7.

I tried the suggestions of these two ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13455939/http-error-404-7-not-found-the-request-filtering-module-is-configured-to-deny), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10871881/iis7-the-request-filtering-module-is-configured-to-deny-a-request-that-exceeds)) SO posts (so I now have a second file on my folder, a `Web.config` file, though the site linked above said nothing about `Web.config` files), nothing helped.

Note that I also followed [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh169179(v=nav.90).aspx) page to register the correct version of ASP.NET with IIS.

Is there any other option?

EDIT:

Windows 7 Ultimate (64-bit), IIS 7.5

Full error (pardon the graphics):

> **Error Summary**
>
> HTTP Error 404.7 - Not Found The request filtering
>       module is configured to deny the file extension.
>
> **Detailed Error Information**
>
> Module:   RequestFilteringModule
>
> Notification: BeginRequest
>
> Handler: StaticFile
>
> Error Code: 0x00000000
>
> Requested URL:    http://localhost:80/MyWebServices/WebService1.asmx.cs
>
> Physical Path:    C:\Users\home\Desktop\MyWebServices\WebService1.asmx.cs
>
> Logon Method:     Not yet determined
>
> Logon User:   Not yet determined

My `Web.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <fileExtensions allowUnlisted="true">
          <remove fileExtension="." />
          <add fileExtension="." allowed="true" />
        </fileExtensions>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Please post the actual, full error and your actual configuration (Windows version, IIS version, XML config) in your question. Also, there's a reason there's no date on that tutorial: it's at least 10 years old. Dump ASMX and go for ASP.NET Web API or WCF.

Comment: Thanks, edit added. I'd certainly move to Web API *and* WCF eventually, but I like to go through the basics and learn about technologies that still being used (in big enterprises, at least), such as ASMX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.cs` is a `code` file and by default all `.cs` files are `not allowed` to be `browsed` in browser of course due to `security concerns` as all `code` is in there.

Also if you want to browse your `webservice` you don't need to `browse .cs` file you need to browse following

```
http://localhost:80/MyWebServices/WebService1.asmx
```

If `MIME Type` for `asmx` is not added you will need to added `MIME Type` for `asmx`.

- Go to IIS
- Select Your `Website/Webservice` on left side.
- Select `MIME Types`.
- Select `Add` on top right.
- Add `.asmx` in `File Name extension` and `text/xml` in `MIME Tpe`

Comment: Well, the 'asmx.cs' file was created in an "asp.net web application" project in VS, and is displayed there as '.asmx', and then I just took it out of the project folder and put it in 'MyWebServices' folder and the '.cs' suffix was added to it automatically. So it would be strange if that is the problem, but i'll try.

Comment: You don't need to took it outside the folder just leave it where it is created by VS.

Comment: I know that, but I wanted a more convenient folder to access, and a Desktop folder was the immediate choice

Comment: You can directly host the webserivce from VS. Go to project properties select `Web` and Select `Local IIS` and click create `Virtual Directory` you can browse by that address.

Comment: Update: It's working! For future reference, here's what I did: Your comment about the `.cs` files made me try doing a little tweak: erasing the `.cs` suffix from the `.asmx.cs` file. I then browsed again with IIS, and got a much more clear error message: That I'm missing a <%@ webservice class="MyNamespace.MyClass" ... %> directive. Then it occured to me that this extension is indeed found in the tutorial I read, but I forgot to add it because VS is dedicating a different `.asmx` file especially for it. So I copied its content to my file, and it worked! BTW, the MIME addition wasn't neccesary.