# How do you deploy Asp.Net web api to IIS on Virtual Machine?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am running Windows 7 Prof on a VMWare Fusion 5 virtual machine hosted on Mac OSX Lion

1. Created a new ASP.Net MVC4 WebAPI project via File New project using VS2012 Express for Web
2. Hit F5 and the default web page displays in the browser
3. Created a new WebSite named MyApi on IIS listening on port 90 and bound it to C:\MyApi
4. Right clicked on the project in VS2012 and used the publish option selecting the website created above
5. When I navigate to `http://localhost:90/` instead of the default web page (from step 1) I get a 403.14 directory listing forbidden error.
6. The new website is configured to run under MyApi App Pool that is configured to run as my logged in account.

What am I missing? How do I get MyAPI up and running.

I want to host it in IIS on Win 7 so I can call the webservice from an app running on my iPhone.

Any help highly appreciated

Answer (score 6):

The answer to this question resolved my issue

[HTTP 404 Page Not Found in Web Api hosted in IIS 7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703090/mvc-4-web-api-iis7-5-http-404-page-not-found)

```
<system.webServer>
    .....
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    .....
</system.webServer>
```