# MVC WebApi endpoints do not work on production, but regular endpoints do

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET MVC project that runs perfectly locally.  It has some controllers that inherit from Controller and some that inherit from ApiController.  My routes are below.  When I run the project through Visual Studio locally, it works perfectly.  I can hit all endpoints and get expected responses.  When I deploy it to a cloud server (Windows Server 2008 r2), only the :Controller endpoints work (those at /p/{controller}/{action}).  None of the endpoints at any :ApiController work.  I get the following error for all of them:

```
{"$id":"1","Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://DOMAIN/CONTROLLER'.","MessageDetail":"No type was found that matches the controller named 'CONTROLLER'."}
```

My routes:

In RouteConfig.cs:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "p/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Redirect", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

In WebApiConfig.cs:

```
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "{controller}",
        defaults: new { }
    );
```

Comment: Routes are probably getting mixed since you are not using a prefix for Web Api controllers. I suggest you try either with a prefix in Web Api like the default project where routeTemplate: "api/{controller}" or disable the MVC routes and try Web Api alone.

Comment: tried both, neither work

Comment: Do you have Elmah installed?  Are you seeing any Errors?

Comment: No errors.  I'm having trouble setting up Elmah now.  I guess I'll keep trying until it works.

Comment: can you make use of log4net to add logging to the code at any point?

Comment: check your global.asax for this line    WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

Comment: @Bart, it's there.  This works locally.

Comment: It doesnt work for all verbs or only PUT/DELETE ?

Comment: It doesn't work for all verbs

Comment: @carlbenson Hi, Was this ever resolved (and if so, how)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied the code to a new webapi project and it works.  It must have been some kind of configuration issue with the old project rather than a dependency missing on the VM, but I still don't know the real cause was.

Comment: Can't you diff the projects and see what the differences are?

Comment: diff the projects will be really interesting. please

Answer (score 0):

There are some related questions to this previously and the answer was the same, create a new API project but the actual problem only had some possible causes, [HTTP 404 Page Not Found in Web Api hosted in IIS 7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703090/mvc-4-web-api-iis7-5-http-404-page-not-found)

Be great to get a diff of the projects.