# MVC5 routing error (404.0) error on IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7.5, iis-8, asp.net-mvc-5.2

An old story of everything works fine on the development machine but not on the host server.

[image]

**HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found**

- Module   *IIS Web Core*
- Notification *MapRequestHandler*
- Handler  *StaticFile*
- Error Code   *0x80070002*

Trying to produce the same error on the development machine by adding `<remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />` to *system.webServer - modules* and resolving it when adding `<add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />`, but that not works on the host. I've also try `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />` but nothing changed.

And here is the *handlers* part:

```
<handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
      <add name="MiniProfiler" path="mini-profiler-resources/*" verb="*" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
</handlers>
```

Few more information:

- MVC.Net 5.2.2.0
- IIS 7.5 on Windows 2008
- Integrated .Net 4.0 application pool.

Is there anything else that I should do?

Now, having the same problem in **IIS8**, any idea?

Comment: Update: The host has solved my problem with no need of any change in my web.config or libraries. I'm asking them how they did it but no answer, yet!

Comment: How did you solve that problem, can you please share it ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have a shared host and they don't tell me how did they fix it. It should be some server configuration or misconfiguration. Sorry, That I cannot help no more :(

Comment: I am facing the same Issue, and not sure how to solve this.

Comment: Next time try checking if there is ISAPi module intalled:
[Web server > modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCLr8.png)
If there is no such records, you can install it via Server management tool:
[Role-based installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9siA.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. It turns out to be discrepancy with Virtual folder name and the URL I was constructing to call Web API route:

```
var URLGetUserAccesses = "/api/Login/GetUserAccesses";
```

Vs.

```
var URLGetUserAccesses = "../api/Login/GetUserAccesses";
```