# API Calls to controller is breaking after deploying to IIS

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, web-deployment

I am invoking API calls to get JSON data from server using javascript.

```
$(function () {

    var customersTable = $('#Customers');
    var returnCustomersTable = UpdateDataTable(customersTable, "/Customers/Loaddata");
}
```

This works fine when I am working with Visual studio Dev environment , because my web application is on root and so all javascripts Works fine.

Example:

**My WebSite URL:** `http://localhost:4391`
**API Calls will be:** `http://localhost:4391/Customers/Loaddata`

This works fine.

But when I deploy application to IIS, my website URL will be,

**My WebSite URL:** `http://localhost/MyAppName`

But API calls would still be,
API Calls will be: `http://localhost/Customers/Loaddata`, which results in not found.

Since I am using javascript in a separate file , I wont be able to do `URL.Action`.

The other option would be to create a base URL for dev and prod and the append with each servcie call.

But I am thinking if there is any other way.

Comment: It makes no difference if its a separate js file. Always use `Url.Action()` to generate your urls. There are plenty of ways to do that. For example just adding a global `var url = '@Url.Action(...)` in the main view which can be read from the plugin. Or if your handling an event of an element, then add a `data-url="@Url.Action(...)"` attribute in the element which can be read in the external file (using `var url = $(this).data('url');`)

Comment: This may helps you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703090/http-404-page-not-found-in-web-api-hosted-in-iis-7-5

Answer (score 1):

The routing configuration in ASP.NET MVC is designed to serve as the *single* place in the application where all of the URLs can be maintained.

It helps considerably with maintenance of the project if all URLs are generated using routing through one of the `UrlHelper` based methods, such as `Url.Action()` rather than hard coded in controllers and views.

As long as your JavaScript is in an MVC view, you can just resolve `Url.Action` inline.

```
$(function () {

    var customersTable = $('#Customers');
    var returnCustomersTable = UpdateDataTable(customersTable, 
        '@Url.Action("Loaddata", "Customers")');
}
```

If the JavaScript is in a separate file outside of MVC, consider passing the URL through a variable or function parameter.

This routing feature also makes it easier to deploy ASP.NET MVC, because the generated URLs will adapt to use the application path when the application is not deployed to the root website virtual directory.

**Application running in IIS web site root:**

```
/Customers/Loaddata
```

**Application running in virtual subdirectory configured as IIS Application named "MyAppName":**

```
/MyAppName/Customers/Loaddata
```