# Having trouble with ASP WebAPI 2.2 and IIS 7 with 404 Error Code

Tags: sql-server, iis, asp.net-web-api

Hello Stack Overflow,

So, I created a ASP REST API with WebAPI 2.2 in Visual Studio 2013. This API returns data from a database in the form of JSON object back to a client calling. Now, I deployed this API to an IIS Distribution on one of our servers running SQL Server 2008, which is running IIS 7.

When making a call to the API we are hit with a 404 error code every time. When I run this API locally it works perfectly fine.

I am unsure on how to continue as i've exhausted most solutions on the net. This stems from redeploying, reinstalling IIS, adding cors (which are still on so it's not CORS related to OUR knowledge) and playing around with the settings in IIS such as application pools.

Any suggestions or pointers would be greatly appreciated. If this question is a little vague, please let me know what kind of information you need.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen 404 errors, when making web API calls, where the web API appears to be looking down the physical directory structure for the logical API path.

This entry details a fix for those issues that may help.
[ASP.NET Web API application gives 404 when deployed at IIS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15389855/asp-net-web-api-application-gives-404-when-deployed-at-iis-7)