# .NET MVC and WebAPI routes giving 404 at localhost/Project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api

Forgive me, I'm a newbie to Microsoft-related technologies.

I have a Web Project running on a local instance of IIS7 (7.5.7600). The project contains routes for both .NET MVC and WebAPI. When I navigate to them by IP address, they come across fine. So, for example, `192.168.2.1/Project` returns the default route. However, if I try to retrieve the same page using a named reference, I get a 404: `localhost/Project` (404) and `mycomp.dev/Project` (404). I can navigate to static resources using these other addresses, so the following return successfully: `localhost/Project/a_file.html` and `mycomp.dev/Project/a_file.html`.

In reading through [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705229/diagnosing-404-errors-on-iis-7-and-asp-net-mvc?rq=1), I saw that other people have resolved similar-looking problems by adding the following to their Web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
</system.webServer>
```

However, these settings are already in my configuration, and the problem persists.

---

I'm not sure if it makes a difference, but I'm running a virtualized copy of Windows on my Mac.