# Pluralsight 404 not found error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a question about `MVC3` in the Pluralsight examples. I'm new to MVC and I have what will appear to be a simple question. I downloaded the sample code and added the `Routemap` to `global.asax.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace OdeToFood
{
    // Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
    // visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801

    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        }

        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Cuisine",
                "cuisine/{name}",
                new { controller = "cuisine", action = "Search" }
                );

          /*  routes.MapRoute(
                "Cuisine",
                "{controller}/{name}",
                new { controller = "cuisine", action = "Search" }
                ); */


            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

        }

        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
    }
}
```

And added the Controller:

```
namespace OdeToFood.Controllers
{
    public class CuisineController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Cuisine/

        public ActionResult Search()
    {
        return Content("You have reached the Cuisine controller");
    }
}
```

}

As shown in the tutorial `"Controller Action Parameter!"` and run the application with the word cuisine (all spelled correctly - even changing to all capitalization as a test) and I still get the `HTTP 404 "not found error"`.

I'm running on `Windows 7` with `VS 2012` and `.net 4.5 installed` (this is a new box and may not have ever had previous versions. `MVC 3` and `MVC 4` are in the new project selection so those must be isntalled correclty.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Did I miss a step? I see that `IIS6` or `IIS7` might/must be on the machine? I have come to believe that IIS doesn't run on windows 7. Is that true? Do I require iis? The sample code works fine until this change...

I'm a little over my head here as I learn this new stuff. Thank you for your patience and help!

Comment: Is your `Search` method in your `CuisineController` is called ? Try to put a breakpoint and take a look. If it not the case, you probably have a mistake with your project architecture, which can be strange if you're not familiar with MVC

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/705229/diagnosing-404-errors-on-iis-7-and-asp-net-mvc ?

Comment: The search method is never called. The route is mapped but never reached when "cuisine" is entered into the address bar:http://localhost:49237/cuisine. (I changed everything back to proper upper/lower case to match the sample code.)  I tried the techniques in the other thread and those do not fix the issue either.

Comment: Can you post the content of the `Application_Start()` method in _Global.asax_?

Comment: I cannot edit my comment so I will add... I was wishing and dreaming that someone had the exact same problem.

Comment: Thank you Alex... I'll post the entrie file because it is not very big...

Comment: added entire file to oroginal post. thanks again.

Comment: FYI. the original project was created in VS2010 and I am opening them in VS2012 which has some upgrading going on...

Comment: Thanks for everyones help and advice. I'm moving on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the a MVC Route Debugger so that you can visually see which routes are being matched. The one I use is Phil Haack's, but there are others available:

```
Install-Package RouteDebugger
```

Separately, don't you need a *name* parameter on your search action to match this route?

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Cuisine",
    "cuisine/{name}",
    new { controller = "cuisine", action = "Search", name = "" }
    );
```

Comment: This did not work. I get the same 404 error. 
The resource cannot be found. 
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /cuisine


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18055