# ASP.NET web forms deployment onto IIS7 giving status code 404 Intermittently

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, http-status-code-404

I have deployed an ASP.NET web forms application to IIS7 and getting status code 404 intermittently.  By this I mean the site will work for say 10 mins, and then I will get status code 404 for 20 mins...

I have one other ASP.NET web forms app running as a separate website on the server, and is running with no problem. (Both are using the same application pool)

I have searched and seen a few people have had similar symptoms but their solutions have not worked for me.  For example this guy was having a similar problem, I have tried their suggestions but no luck.

[Diagnosing 404 errors on IIS 7 and ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705229/diagnosing-404-errors-on-iis-7-and-asp-net-mvc)

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: The application is hosted on a Windows Server?

Comment: @Carlos487 Yes Windows Server 2008 R2, & IIS7.

Comment: Mmm... Maybe the app is crashing have you checked the Windows Event Viewer

Comment: Yes i have looked at the event logs.  I should of mentioned the app works fine when I deploy to my local IIS in development environment.

Comment: Have you checked which Framework version is the app pool using and which is the app created with... Maybe you are using 4.5.1 and your server has only 4.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem turned out to be a DNS issue, there were two DNS records set for the subdomain.  Hence the intermittent problem.  There was a 50/50 chance which ip it got and cached.