# IIS 7 returns 404 for all requests

Tags: iis

I have a default website and 2 applications underneath it. One is a WCF service on "http,net.tcp". The other is an asp.net site.

When I browse to the service, static files, the asp.net site or the default website I get a blank 404 response. The raw response in fiddler is "HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"

I've tried reinstalling IIS. I thought it might be the handlers so I've had a look at the list but they exactly match a machine that does not have this issue.

The local 'hosts' file is empty and the machine.config file has not been manually edited.

(I can still connect to the service 'dsxwebservice' with tcp, and this issue has only been present for a few days, probably triggered by some change I've made to the configuration / install)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skype was hogging port 80

I came to this conclusion from using this on the command line:

netstat -ano

Then finding the PID against port 80 in Task Manager

Then quitting skype and seeing the issue go away.

I resolved the conflict by changing Skype settings to leave port 80 alone. This also explains why the 404 was not an IIS styled 404 page and why there was nothing in the IIS logs - just a question mark against the default website icon.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen [Diagnosing 404 errors on IIS 7 and ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705229/diagnosing-404-errors-on-iis-7-and-asp-net-mvc/16475231#16475231)?

You can also see if [Failed Request Tracing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731798(v=WS.10).aspx) can shed some light on your specific scenario.