# ASP.NET MVC app has SecurityException

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to get an ASP.NET MVC app working... I should have known it wouldn't be easy. The first few pages work, but they are all static. The first time a Controller is executed I get the exception below.

Here is the Controller action method:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ActionResult Index(Section? section, int? parent)
{
    if (section == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Questions", new {section = Section.Section0});
    }

    IPagedList<Question> questions = _surveyService.FetchQuestions(User.Identity.Name, section.Value, parent);

    // ...

    ViewResult result = View("Index", questions);
    result.ViewData.Add("CurrentSection", section.Value);
    result.ViewData.Add("Parent", parent);
    result.ViewData.Add("IsLastPage", questions.IsLastPage);

    return result;
}
```

The exception is thrown in the second line of the method at `RedirectToAction()`.

Background:

- I've followed the instructions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266205/is-there-a-way-that-i-can-run-a-asp-net-mvc-project-on-godaddy-com-shared-web-hos/299339#299339).
- I'm not using reflection or demanding security explicitly in my code.
- I'm using **MVC**, **LINQ to SQL**, [**Elmah**](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/), and [**PagedList**](http://pagedlist.codeplex.com/).
- I'm using **IIS 7** with
  **Integrated** mode.
- I added [**assembly:
  AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers**] to my
  AssemblyInfo.cs. I did this because I found another Stack Overflow question that had an answer recommending it (I can't find it now, or else I would provide a link). I also strong named my assemblies as suggested by Rex M's answer below.

---

What am I missing to make this work?

The exception:

```
Server Error in '/surveys/objectification' Application.
    Security Exception
    Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.

    Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers.

    Source Error:

    An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

    Stack Trace:

    [SecurityException: That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers.]
       SelfObjectificationSurvey.Web.Controllers.QuestionsController.Index(Nullable`1 section, Nullable`1 parent) +0
       lambda_method(ExecutionScope , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +123
       System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +17
       System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +178
       System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +24
       System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassa.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__7()
+53
       System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +258
       System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassc.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__9()
+20
       System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +193
       System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
+382
       System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
+123
       System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +23
       System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +7
       System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext) +144
       System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext) +54
       System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext) +7
       System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
+181
       System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
+75


    Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3074; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4049
```

Comment: I'm curious, how did a 7 year old question with an accepted answer get closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One other thing you may want to check is that, according to this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnfa/archive/2005/02/04/367390.aspx), there are some .NET Types that can not be used within a partially trusted assembly, even if it has been decorated with AllowPartiallyTrustedCallersAttribute.

See [.NET Framework Assemblies and the AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302328.aspx) for a full list.

**Update 2**
Are you sure all the third-party assemblies you are calling are also decorated with the AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers attribute?

eg looking at the AssemblyInfo.cs for PagedList 1.1 it does not seem to contain this attribute.

**Update 1**: You are right, that list of unusable types does look very dated.

This [LINQ to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386929.aspx) FAQ has some interesting information regarding its usage in a partial trust environment:

> APTCA
>
> Q. Is System.Data.Linq marked for use
>   by partially trusted code?
>
> A. Yes, the System.Data.Linq.dll
>   assembly is among those .NET Framework
>   assemblies marked with the
>   AllowPartiallyTrustedCallersAttribute
>   attribute. Without this marking,
>   assemblies in the .NET Framework are
>   intended for use only by fully trusted
>   code.
>
> The principal scenario in LINQ to SQL
>   for allowing partially trusted callers
>   is to enable the LINQ to SQL assembly
>   to be accessed from Web applications,
>   where the trust configuration is
>   Medium.

Comment: That's an old list (.NET 1.1), and I would hope that System.Data.SqlClient isn't still on it.

Comment: So far I've removed elmah and I still got the exception, PagedList is next ...

Comment: PagedList was the problem, thanks! I recompiled it with the AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers attribute and it worked. I'll log an issue for this on the codeplex in case others get tripped up on this.

Answer (score 2):

Are your assemblies [strong-named](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wd40t7ad.aspx)?

> AllowPartiallyTrustedCallersAttribute is only effective when applied by a strong-named assembly at the assembly level.

Comment: No, they are not. I'll give that a try.

Comment: I added a strong name key, recompiled, uploaded and tried it again. It gave the same exception =/

Answer (score 2):

Back out your assemblies one-by-one to see who the culprit is.  No need in guessing.  I  had this issue with the Microsoft Enterprise Libraries.

Comment: So far I've removed elmah and I still got the exception, PagedList is next ...

Comment: Saw you got it resolved, glad this helped.

Comment: It did! If could accept multiple answers, I would accept this one too.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to need the full trust mode to run your code. Most hosts only allow medium trust, as GoDaddy also does. You may have to switch your host to another one that will give you the full trust.

Although MVC on its own should not require more than medium trust, your other code however may. It will suffice you to have run-time type check somewhere in your code in order to enact reflection which in its turn will want to have the full trust.

Comment: According to this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/266205/is-there-a-way-that-i-can-run-a-asp-net-mvc-project-on-godaddy-com-shared-web-hos/299339#299339, you can host ASP.NET MVC in medium trust with GoDaddy. The only things I've added is LINQ to SQL and PagedList. As much as I loathe GoDaddy, I don't want to switch before my account expires next year.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ to SQL may the issue - LINQ to SQL usually generates a stored procedure. If your code is trying to do that in medium trust it could be causing the APTCA exception.

Comment: LINQ to SQL does not generate stored procedures ... at lease not in my project.