# How to upload/publish ASP.net MVC application to Godaddy on my domain

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment

I have developed the ASP.NET application in MVC using Visual studio 2010 express edition. I have domain on Godaddy. how to deploy the MVC application on godaddy ? What steps i need to follow?

Comment: which version of .net you are using? what is your hosting plan?

Comment: using 4.0 version with windows hosting plan.

Answer (score 1):

1) Publish you site on you local test machine.

2) Login to Control Panel of Go-Deddy.

3) From content select File  file manager and upload you content.

4) Give proper connection string.

That's it...........

Above is high level steps.. You c[an check](http://ammonsonline.com/2008/04/godaddy-and-aspnet-apps-aspx/) for better explanations.

Answer (score 1):

It's important to note that if your app is using MVC, you will need to [bin deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266205/is-there-a-way-that-i-can-run-a-asp-net-mvc-project-on-godaddy-com-shared-web-ho) it for it to work on GoDaddy.  You will need to manually copy any MVC related DLLs that your project is using to your production bin directory.

Alternatively, you can set "Copy Local" equal to "true" in the Properties window for any of your MVC related project references as described in [this blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx). Then when you do a Publish of your application, all of the needed assemblies will be included automatically.

Be sure to deploy [the correct versions](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253806) of the DLLs you need.

Answer (score 1):

sure, you can deploy your MVC 4 application. Godaddy supports MVC 4. What I have done to deploy my MVC 4 application is:

**1. I included DLLs such as:**

- System.Web.Mvc
- System.Web.Routing
- System.Web.Abstractions

**2. I edited web.config file. I put next strings:**

```
<system.web>
   <trust level="Medium"/>
   .....  
</system.web>
```

**3. Then I used the File System publish method and then I used FileZilla to transfer the files to the GoDaddy.** I copied all files to httpdocs directory. You must copy just to *httpdocs directory.*

That's all. Good luck.