# ASP.NET regarding CS0246: The type or namespace name - Error

Tags: c#, asp.net

Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'webmarketingEntities1' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

[image]

This is the last error of the errors chain I'm receiving while trying to publish that website...

How can I fix it? that's one...

Is there any reference that can guide me through the publishing process?

Keep in mind that the website runs completely perfect locally, I'm only getting these errors after I uploaded the data to godaddy server...

Comment: Can you post text instead of an image?

Comment: you web is not publsihed corectly dll is missing

Comment: How are you publishing? Are you using a publish profile (pubxml) or other method?

Comment: Is the class `webmarketingEntities1` in your current project? 
If its in other project, make sure that other project in on your reference project of current one

Comment: @Ashish Yes it is, and its not in any other project.

Comment: @user1503106 I uploaded all of the DLL files at the bin folder after building the solution, are you referring to something else?

Comment: @SimonMartin I don't know what is the pubxml @_@

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely an issue with a missing DLL on publish.  Your webMarketingEntities class is most likely a DLL reference, correct?  If so, open solution explorer, go to references in your project, find your DLL and choose Properties.  In the copy local property, choose True.  In short, when you publish your website, not all the required DLL's are being output.

Answer (score 1):

For a walk through using Visual Studio to publish you can check out  the following on the asp.net website: 
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-production - the process is very similar for publishing to GoDaddy and not Azure

Alternatively you can try something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/12581589/96505, which suggests building the site locally then using an ftp client to deploy. This will give you the opportunity to check that webmarketingEntities1 is included.