# Deploying a asp.net mvc4 application to godaddy

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I created an ASP.NET MVC4 application using C# on Visual Studio 2012. But facing a hard time deploying it. I uploaded all the folders of my project onto my server (godaddy). But still cant view my website running.

My question: Is this enough to deploy my site ? Or anything else needed?

Comment: Some more facts would be required. What hosting package are you using with godaddy? Does a static html page work?

Comment: I'm pretty sure GoDaddy [doesn't support MVC4 yet](http://support.godaddy.com/groups/web-hosting/forum/topic/go-daddy-compatible-with-asp-net-mvc-4-razor-syntaxe/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can [bin deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266205/is-there-a-way-that-i-can-run-a-asp-net-mvc-project-on-godaddy-com-shared-web-ho) an MVC4 app to GoDaddy.

Just copy the relevant MVC4 related DLLs that you need to your production bin directory.

Alternatively, you can set "Copy Local" equal to "true" in the Properties window for any of your MVC4 related project references as described in [this blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx).  Then when you do a Publish of your application, all of the needed assemblies will be included automatically.

You probably won't need all of these, but in an MVC4 app I currently manage on GoDaddy, I needed to manually include the [correct versions](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253806) of DLLs for:

- System.Web.Abstractions.dll
- System.Web.Helpers.dll
- System.Web.Mvc.dll
- System.Web.Optimization.dll
- System.Web.Razor.dll
- System.Web.Routing.dll
- System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll
- System.Web.WebPages.dll
- System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll

Comment: I have a Windows Deluxe hosting plan, but any Windows plan should work.

Comment: did you just use the button "Pubish" in VS2012 and fill in all required columns in the dialog?(host, name, ...)

Comment: Yes, the blog post link (http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx) walks you through this using the Publish Wizard.

Comment: I've created a local folder with my project files and have uploaded to godaddy by filezilla. However, I've got the error: 500 - Internal server error. Did you upload files by filezilla or just use "Publish" button of VS2012?

Comment: I did a "Publish" to a local directory and then uploaded everything to GoDaddy via FileZilla.

Comment: Have you putted all files in the root? I've putted all files in the root, however it was an idle attempt.

Comment: please see my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21159691/cannot-deploy-mvc-4-at-godaddy/21161720?noredirect=1#21161720

Answer (score 0):

sure, you can deploy your MVC 4 application. Godaddy supports MVC 4.
What I have done to deploy my MVC 4 application is:

**1. I included DLLs such as:**

- System.Web.Mvc
- System.Web.Routing
- System.Web.Abstractions

**2. I edited web.config file. I put next strings:**

```
    <system.web>
        <trust level="Medium"/>
        .....  
    </system.web>
```

**3. Then I used the File System publish method** and then I used FileZilla to transfer the files to the GoDaddy. I copied all files to **httpdocs** directory. **You must copy just to **httpdocs*** directory.*

That's all. Good luck.

Comment: Please help me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46399021/how-to-deploy-asp-net-mvc-5-application-using-visual-studio