# Cannot deploy MVC 4 to server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-deployment

My web application is just a simple web application made in VS 2010 MVC 4 without any code from outside. It's just default application of VS 2010. I have Deluxe Windows Hosting with Plesk. I've never changed any feature in my account. I copy all my files to "//Root Directory". Beside my files I see various folderssuch as: ", plesk, erro-docs, cgi-bin, logs" - I do not have permissions to delete them.

All my projects are "Release" configuration. I've tried all ways which I met in the Internet:

*1.I copied three libraries to bin directory:* 
System.Web.Mvc, System.Web.Routing, System.Web.Abstractions

These dll's I copied from GAC(C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL).  I putted such strings in web.config: < trust level="Medium"/>. I used local deployment(to directory) in VS2010 by button "Publish". No result.

*2.I copied 9 libraries to bin directory:*

System.Web.Abstractions.dll 
System.Web.Helpers.dll 
System.Web.Mvc.dll 
System.Web.Optimization.dll 
System.Web.Razor.dll
System.Web.Routing.dll 
System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll 
System.Web.WebPages.dll 
System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll.

These dll's I copied from GAC(C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL). I used local deployment(to directory) in VS2010 by button "Publish". I putted such strings: < trust level="Medium"/>. No result.

*3.I copied three libraries to bin directory*: System.Web.Mvc, System.Web.Routing, System.Web.Abstractions - these dll's I copied from GAC(C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL). I putted such strings: < trust level="Medium"/>. I used deployment via ftp option in VS2010 by button "Publish". No result.

*4.I copied three libraries to bin directory:*
System.Web.Abstractions.dll 
System.Web.Helpers.dll 
System.Web.Mvc.dll 
System.Web.Optimization.dll 
System.Web.Razor.dll
System.Web.Routing.dll 
System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll 
System.Web.WebPages.dll 
System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll - these dll's I copied from GAC(C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL). I putted such strings: < trust level="Medium"/>. I used deployment via ftp in VS2010 by button "Publish" No result.

*5.I've tried to upload  files via filezzilla*. < trust level="Medium"/>. However it was an idle attempt.

*6.I've tried to upload  files via browsers*.  However it was an idle attempt.

*7.I've tried to upload  zip-files via browser and extract them at godaddy server.* < trust level="Medium"/>. However it was an idle attempt.

All above-listed attempts result the word on the screen: *"nup.com  My site is launching soon."*
Nothing changes.

**I have a question.**

**What I do wrong?**

I've read all articles by Phil Haack http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx. Any help will be gratefully appreciated!:)

Comment: Are you using a GoDaddy hosting account that supports .NET? What's all this GAC stuff? Just right click your project and choose Publish and use "File System". Zip that up and unzip it and you're away! Aside from whatever you need to do with GoDaddy to make turn the folder into an "Application" in IIS.

Comment: @ta.speot.is , yeah, I did like you said. However, it does not any result.  My plan is Deluxe Windows Hosting with Plesk and it supports .NET.

Comment: What is the result? You visit the page and you get an error? What is the error message?

Comment: @ta.speot.is ,   500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed. I've sent just default application without any code from me.

Comment: Most providers give you a way to view the error logs. More information should be in there.

Comment: @ta.speot.is how can I see the errors?  Should I write a message or what should I do to know more about errors? It is just a default application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done all actions to deploy correctly but I copied all files to a wrong folder. The problem was that **I just copied all my files to a wrong directory**. I called to godaddy support and they said that I copied my files to wrong directory.

When I copied all files to **"httpdocs"** directory then my mvc 4 application start working!:).

Thank you a lot, guys. Good luck.

Answer (score 8):

Ok - you have a lot of questions inside your single question.  I am going to try and take these one at a time as well as some of your commentary so that we can a) understand the build/publish process of an MVC app and b) hopefully get your project running over at GoDaddy.

> 1.If I change in web.config , then should I recompile my project and upload again?

No, unless you change the web.config locally and you need to upload those changes.  If you FTP/connect to the web.config on the actual web server, IIS will automatically restart (reload) your application so that it can apply the web.config changes.  After a web.config change, you will notice the first request will take 10-20 seconds.  This is IIS restarting your application.  If you change the web.config locally, then yes, you should rebuild/reupload.

> 2.Is it correct to copy a project to root of directory?

The way you have phrased this question makes me think that yes, you are doing it wrong.  When you create a project in Visual Studio, you get a solution folder on your actual hard drive.  If you are compiling that project, then copying the entire solution folder to your web server, then yes, this is not the correct way to do it.  What you want to do is create a `Publishing Profile`.  You can either deploy your application via Web Deploy (unsure if GoDaddy supports this), FTP, or File System.  By going through the Visual Studio publishing process, the compiler a) compiles your application per your settings (Debug or Release), b) applies the proper Web.Config transformations and c) **only** outputs the files necessary to run your application.  The third part is important.  All of your .cs files (controllers, models, etc) get compiled into a .dll and that is what needs to be deployed, not the actual source code files.  The publishing process does this for you.

I would recommend you create a folder on your dev machine somewhere, and then create a publishing profile that publishes your application to that folder.  It is the contents of that folder that you want to FTP to your web server.  To create a publishing profile, right click your MVC project and select `Publish`.  This will bring up the wizard for you to set things up.

> 3.What I do wrong?

Kind of hard to say at this point.  It could be that you are not compiling your application correctly.  FTP sounds bonked, but that is not an MVC/Visual Studio issue.  For FTP issues with Plesk on GoDaddy (and other items), check this [help link here.](http://support.godaddy.com/help/category/281/dedicated-linux-plesk)

```
4.how can I see the errors? Should I write a message or what should I do to know more about errors?
```

You should be able to control this in your web.config.  Open your web.config file up and check for a couple of lines.  You want to turn off custom errors and set the compilation to debug mode.  This does two things.  One, the error you get back from the server will be way more detailed and being in debug mode allows IIS/.NET to actually show you the line of code that is causing the problem.

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>
  </system.web>
```

Be aware that if you do have a web.config transformation, this could actually turn these setting off.  Ensure that your publishing profile is set to deploy the `Debug` configuration while you test deploying your site.  Once you are happy with your results, set it back to `Release` configuration so that your site runs faster as well as does not display code lines to potentially bad people if an error does occur.

> 5.I copied 9 libraries to bin directory...

Ok, this could also be a problem.  You do not need to copy anything to your bin directory.  If you want to include referenced assemblies in your published project, all you need to do is open the `References` folder under your project.  From there, right click any assembly that you want to include in your project when you publish and select `Properties`.  Inside of the properties pane, you will see the option to `Copy Local`.  Set this to true.  This tells the compiler to copy that assembly to the output folder during the publishing process (see, that publishing thing does lots of good stuff for you!)  I would do this for all assemblies in your project that are MVC related.  You can experiment with this (like one at a time) until you find the right combination of assemblies that you need to include in your project to make it run on the GoDaddy server.  I have not used GoDaddy hosting in quite a while, so I do not know what their current capabilities are.

Last thoughts, I think MVC 4 is .NET 4 or higher.  Ensure that GoDaddy supports .NET 4 or higher or else you really won't be able to host this on that server (even using bin deploy) and will need to find additional hosting.  [Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/solutions/web/) has some really great deals right now and [Gearhost](http://www.gearhost.com/cloudhosting/cloudsites/) is very reliable but a little pricey (though they are completely simple to use).

**EDIT**

Just a little more info on GoDaddy - ensure that you set your site up correctly before you try any of this.  You need to have Windows hosting (most likely) and it should be setup to use the Integrated App pool (else, it would appear you never uploaded anything since there is no 'default document').  At this point, I wonder if your hosting account was provisioned correctly for what you want to do.  http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/6639/do-your-hosting-accounts-support-mvc3-applications  (Yes, I know it says MVC 3, but the setup applies equally to MVC 4)

Comment: good job! However, I've tried all ways to deploy an application. I've created "Publish profiel to use "web deploy" of "FTP-deploy". But they do not have any effect. I just see the words:"My site is launching soon. "

Comment: @StepUp  Did you try to publish to a local folder and then FTP to your site using an FTP client?  Also, I would recommend that you delete any files that are already there (on your FTP site), then deploy.

Comment: yeah, I tried to publish to a local folder and then upload to FTP. It does not work. Godaddy support said I could deploy a mvc project. But all my attempts were idle.

Comment: What does "idle" mean?  If no files are transferring up, sounds like an FTP issue.  Possibly a firewall blocking the connection?

Comment: I uploaded files by button "Publish" of VS2012 to FTP. However, my mvc 4 application is not run. It still shows "my site is soon launching". Any advices?

Comment: @Stepup - I would assume you have not setup the web server correctly in that you have to have the pipeline set to integrated, correct right version of .NET framework, etc.  Your results sound like a site that has no index.html file and the .NET handler is not taking over routing to provide the default view.  Your question is now moving toward the help my setup my hosting provider, which we really cannot do over a Q&A forum.  I would contact GoDaddy and tell them you need a .NET 4+ app pool with pipeline set to Integrated.

Comment: godaddy support said a pipeline was set to integrated by default.I really do not know what I can do.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps...

1. Depends what you've changed, some changes might at least require an application pool reset.
2. Root of what directory? It should generally be inside inetpub/YOURWEBSITEFOLDERHERE
3. You have assumed that GoDaddy supports MVC 4, I could only find references to them supporting [MVC 3 Support](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/6639/do-your-hosting-accounts-support-mvc3-applications)

There are rumours that if you deploy the bin and mvc dll there is a way around this but I couldn't find any details.

Have a read of the [MVC 3 deploy instructions](http://windows2008hosting.asphostportal.com/post/Cheap-ASPNET-MVC-3-Hosting-ASPHostPortal-How-to-Deploy-an-ASPNET-MVC-3-App-to-Web-Hosting-with-5cbin-Deployment.aspx)

EDIT: In answer to comment below:

1. Editing  could have a knock on effect and so i would advise towards a recompile, e.g. change to medium trust might have an affect if DLLs don't work in partial trust mode, and recompilation might well highlight these issues.
2. Sounds ok, test by putting a html file up with some text and try and get to it in your browser.
3. I've seen people talking about it, mostly saying it's not supported, try the MVC deploy instructions above to bin deploy MVC 4; it works with 3, it might work with 4.

Comment: 1. I edit just <trust/> tag.2. I have a domain name which I've got at godaddy. So I copy files to my domain - "www.hhh.com" //root directory. 3. I've seen topics where people talks about MVC4 at godaddy

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried bin deploying MVC4?
http://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/25/bin-deploying-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx/
or
http://forums.asp.net/t/1884928.aspx

To answer your question:

1. Changes to web.config should not require the project to be recompiled.

Comment: yeah, I've tried it. However, it was an idle attempt. Does it work for you?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with a MVC4 I had running on hosting on Godaddy using Plesk. Suddenly, without any changes, site began to display "Site Launching Soon" Page. At first I thought it was hacked. After calling godaddy support, the agent told me that the site must need at least one html file as a start point (index.html, index.aspx, default.aspx - source: http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/60/what-file-displays-when-someone-browses-to-my-domain-name?locale=en&ci=46061), which seemed odd because it was working fine all the time.

Then, after some trial - error stuff, I could solve my problem by going to the Plesk hosting management, and navigate to:

**Websites & Domains > [domain name] > Web Server Settings for domain. And there, change the Default Document setting to "Default".**

We never touched that setting, not sure really why it suddenly changed.

Hope that helps!

Comment: We've taken the first step. Now I have another error: "Forbidden. You do not have permission to access this document. 
Web Server at nup.com". Have you ever met such an error?

Comment: Yes I did, however, it went away when changed that setting and when I deleted the pages injected by GoDaddy (site launching soon..), delete the Default.aspx and the index.html on your site's FTP root, then try again.

Comment: What a setting did you change? I deleted pages Default.aspx and index.html but I still see the error: "Forbidden
 You do not have permission to access this document.Web Server at nup.com". I tried to delete the pages injected by GoDaddy (site launching soon..) but godaddy server said: "Unable to remove /error_docs/unsupported_media_type.html: Access denied". How to delete this files?

Comment: did you do anything except what you have written?

Comment: hey there, nope, those were the only changes applied. 1. delete "launching soon pages" on the FTP root folder (httpdocs or the one that contains your domain). 2. set default document setting variable to "Default". verify that, I will review if I did other change.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps . . .

> Global.asax should be your default index . . . in godaddy server settings.
>
> I had a similar problem and was able to solve it.
>
> I have two other mvc application sites hosted on godaddy, but not with their new plesk hosting.
>
> After calling tech support and not having any luck there I did some reading on their hosting.
>
> Their plesk hosting must have an index.
>
> So, a few hours later it dawned on me to point their start point to my Global.asax in their server settings.
>
> And, viola! my site was up and running.

Comment: I opened "web server settings" and deleted all offered values by goddaddy( Index.html, 
Index.htm, Index.cfm) and entered just Global.asax. However, I still see the error: "Forbidden You do not have permission to access this document.Web Server at nup.com".
What can I try to do anything?

Comment: Perhaps it is indeed just a permission issue in the way the directory structure is set up on Godaddy.  Have you called them? They seem fairly motivated to help as long as you don't run into anything too complicated that involves site content.

Comment: it is really expensive to call to godaddy support as I live in Mongolia.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue until I set customErrors to off (first line).  then I started seeing security policy issues which was remedied (second line).

(I'm using Godaddy)